# Asymptotic growth (Big o notation)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

What I am trying to do is to sort the following functions:

n, n^3, nlogn, n/logn, n/log^2n, sqrt(n), sqrt(n^3)

in increasing order of asymptotic growth.

What I did is,

n/logn, n/log^2n, sqrt(n), n, sqrt(n^3), nlogn, n^3.

1) Is my answer correct?

2) I know about the time complexity of the basic functions such as n, nlogn, n^2, but I am really confused on the functions like, n/nlogn, sqrt(n^3).
How should I figure out which one is faster or slower? Is there any way to do this with mathematical calculations?

3) Are the big O time complexity and asymptotic growth different thing?

I would be really appreciated if anyone blows up my confusion... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An important result we need here is:

> `log n` grows more slowly than `n^a` for any *strictly* positive number `a > 0`.

For a proof of the above, see [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial).

If we re-write `sqrt(n^3)` as `n^1.5`, we can see than `n log n` grows more slowly (divide both by `n` and use the result above).

Similarly, `n / log n` grows more *quickly* than any `n^b` where `b < 1`; again this is directly from the result above. Note that it is however slower than `n` by a factor of `log n`; same for `n / log^2 n`.

Combining the above, we find the increasing order to be:

1. `sqrt(n)`
2. `n / log^2 n`
3. `n / log n`
4. `n`
5. `n log n`
6. `sqrt(n^3)`
7. `n^3`

So I'm afraid to say you got only a few of the orderings right.

---

**EDIT**: to answer your other questions:

- If you take the limit of `f(n) / g(n)` as `n -> infinity`, then it can be said that `f(n)` is asymptotically greater than `g(n)` if this limit is infinite, and lesser if the limit is zero. This comes directly from the [definition of big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).
- big-O is a method of classifying asymptotic growth, typically as the parameter approaches infinity.